# link to follow on tooltip is shown but doesn't bring me there

Tags: php, javascript, onclick, tooltip, href

Using the code at the bottom, the a href part does show the relevant link where my mouse is at, but when I click it it just redirects to .../index.php#.

I need some coding help - so it redirects me to the actual url - which is held in var totalService3 = data.getValue(e.row, 4); and as I said, is being shown in the tooltip div.

regards
Peter

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(tree, 'onmouseover', function (e) {

    var provider = data.getValue(e.row, 0);
    var totalService = data.getValue(e.row, 2);
    var totalService2 = data.getValue(e.row, 3);
    var totalService3 = data.getValue(e.row, 4);

    // populate the tooltip with data
    $('#tooltipTopLine').html(provider);
    $('#tooltipMiddleLine').html(totalService);
    $('#tooltipBottomLine').html(totalService2);
    $('#tooltipHyperlink').html(totalService3);
    // show the tooltip
    $('#tooltip').show();

});



google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
// make the tooltip div follow the mouse

$(function () {

    $('#visualization').mousemove(function (e) {

        $('#tooltip').css({

            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY - 40

        });

    });

});

}
```

```
<div id="container" style="width:400px; height: 1200px;padding-top: 20px;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>

    <div id="tooltip" style="padding-bottom:10px;"> <span id="tooltipTopLine"></span>
        <br />Price 1 <span id="tooltipMiddleLine"></span>
        <br />Price 2 <span id="tooltipBottomLine"></span>
        <br /><a href="#" id="tooltipHyperlink">Link</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: you need to set your href on your anchor to the target of the link.

Comment: aren't anchors for linking within a webpage only?

Comment: they are for linking to any url.

Comment: @Orangepill that's what I am trying, but actually that comes down to my original question; I know what, but don't know how...do you?

Comment: $('#tooltip').find('a').attr("href", newurl);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(tree, 'onmouseover', function (e) {

    // your code

    $('#tooltip a').attr('href', totalService3);
    // show the tooltip
    $('#tooltip').show();
});
```

or

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(tree, 'onmouseover', function (e) {

    //your code

    $('#tooltipHyperlink').attr('href', totalService3);
    // show the tooltip
    $('#tooltip').show();
});
```

Comment: It's generating the following error respinse:
Uncaught ReferenceError: totalService3 is not defined

Comment: So why works `$('#tooltipHyperlink').html(totalService3);` in your code ? Did you put my code in your `onmouseover` function ?

Comment: ...it was outside my mouseover function...now it's working (option nr 2): for which I have to thank you very much. Regards Peter.